# PHP contextual filter code in drupal 7 'no query was run'

Tags: views

I am using the contextual filter code in views to filter more options for the view, using this snippet:

```
$uid= $GLOBALS['user']->uid;

$result = db_query('SELECT users_node__field_data_field_agencyname.field_agencyname_nid as agencyid
FROM {field_data_field_agencyname} users_node__field_data_field_agencyname 
WHERE users_node__field_data_field_agencyname.entity_id=:uid AND users_node__field_data_field_agencyname.deleted=0 AND users_node__field_data_field_agencyname.entity_type=:user',array(':uid'=>$uid,':user'=>'user'));

return $result->agencyid;
```

but no query is run shows up on the sql pane ?

How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect that no query is run because your code snippet isn't returning anything. The thing that jumps out to me is that you are trying to use $result as the first row returned by the query, however it is actually the entire result set.  For example, retrieving data from a DB usually look similar to the code below:

```
$result = db_query($sql);

// Iterate over the collection ($result).
foreach ($result as $record) {
  $agency_id = $record->agencyid;
}
```

In the example you posted above, you could use the following code snippet to pull a single field from the first row in the result set:

```
// This would return the agency ID.
return db_query($sql)->fetchField();
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3a%3afetchField/7) of fetchField() for more information on how it is used.

Comment: I realized this after a while of using views. :D Thank you! Your answer will be added to my knowledge with using drupal more!

Comment: Sometimes Views and Drupal can be a little unforgiving. Glad you are using Drupal more, and good luck!